# mongoDB : multi value field search ignoring null fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I am trying to make a search on several field where some of them can be left blank.
Given the following Json document in MongoDB (only three fields here, but N fields in reality, with N > 10) :

```
{
    'first_name' : 'value_X',
    'last_name' : 'value_Y',
    'mail_adress' : 'value_Z'

}
```

Then let's suppose a form where the user can enter the value of the first name, last name, mail address and phone number.
If all the field are filled the query in MongoDB looks like :

```
db.collection.find( {
                        'first_name' : 'value_A',
                        'last_name' : 'value_B',
                        'mail_adress' : 'value_C'

                    }
                )
```

The problem I have is that I might have some fields left blank by the user :
It means that my query can also become :

```
db.collection.find({ 'first_name' : 'value_A' })
```

or

```
db.collection.find( {'last_name' : 'value_B'})
```

or

```
db.collection.find( {'mail_adress' : 'value_C'})
```

or

```
db.collection.find( {'first_name' : 'value_A','last_name' : 'value_B'})
```

or

```
db.collection.find( {'first_name' : 'value_A','last_name' : 'value_C'})
```

or

```
db.collection.find( {'last_name' : 'value_B','mail_adress' : 'value_C'})
```

I would like to know if I need to write a query for each particular instance ?
I also thought to generate query dynamically depending on the field entered by a user, it would be easy as query are Json doucment.

I am also wondering if MongoDB could  **ignore field if they are null** (but I don't want to lose performance in my query)

Anyone can help me ? Thanks

EDIT on 20140404 at 6PM : part of answer

Here is the Python code with Aditya suggestion.
I also added the python code about generating the query in front end as svjn suggested:

```
'''
Created on 4 Apr 2014

@author: scoulombel
'''

import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
import random
import string



# fill the database
def fillCollection(collection):
    doc =   {
      'first_name' : 'value_X',
      'last_name' : 'value_Y',
      'mail_adress' : 'value_Z'

    }

    docID = collection.insert(doc)

    for _ in range(0,10):
        doc = {
           'first_name' : ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for _ in range(4)) + ''.join(random.choice(string.digits) for _ in range(4)),
           'last_name' : ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for _ in range(4)) + ''.join(random.choice(string.digits) for _ in range(4)),
           'mail_adress' : ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for _ in range(4)) + ''.join(random.choice(string.digits) for _ in range(4))

        }
        docID = collection.insert(doc)

# read data in a cursor
def readCursor(cursor):
    object_list = []
    count = 0   
    for doc in cursor :
        del doc["_id"]
        count += 1
        doc['resOrder'] =  count
        object_list.append(doc)

    print object_list

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    #client = MongoClient()
    client = MongoClient('ip', 'port')
    db = client.test_OR_AND_DB      
    collection = db.collection

    fillCollection(collection)

    # SEARCH VALUE which can be null or not    
    value_A = 'value_X'
    value_B = 'null' #'value_Y'
    value_C = 'null' #'value_Z'

    # APPROACH 1 : ADITYA answer for search
    cursor1 = db.collection.find(
                                {
                         '$or' : [
                                    { '$and' : [ {'first_name' : { '$ne': 'null' }}, {'first_name' : value_A } ]},
                                    { '$and' : [ {'last_name' :  { '$ne': 'null' }}, {'last_name'  : value_B  } ]}, 
                                    { '$and' : [ {'mail_adress' :{ '$ne' :'null' }}, {'mail_adress':value_C } ]}
                               ]
                        }
                        )

    readCursor(cursor1)

    # APPROACH 2 ; create a JSON representing the query dynamically
    path_value_dict = {'first_name':value_A, 'last_name':value_B, 'mail_address':value_C} # if embedded it would be for instance name.first_name 
    query= {}
    for key in path_value_dict.keys():
        if path_value_dict[key] != 'null':
            query[key] = path_value_dict[key]


    print query
    cursor2 = db.collection.find({'first_name': 'value_X', 'mail_adress': 'value_Z'})
    readCursor(cursor2)
```

Comment: How you are querying the db? are you using any frontend language like Java to make db calls? or you directly querying db on mongo console? what's exactly your requirement?

Comment: *frontend* language like Java ? o_O

Comment: I am using Python, with the pymongo driver, and Tornado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Mongodb [**$or**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) operator for your query.

The $or operator performs a logical OR operation on an array of two or more `<expressions>` and selects the documents that satisfy *at least one* of the `<expressions>`.

### Use :

```
db.collection.find({
     $or : [{ $and : [ {'first_name' : { $ne:null }, {'first_name' :'value_A' }]},
            { $and : [ {'last_name' :  { $ne:null }, {'last_name'  :'value_B' }]}, 
            { $and : [ {'mail_addres' :{ $ne:null }, {'mail_addres':'value_C'}]}
           ]}
    );
```

Comment: I don't think so this could be the solution he is looking for. For example, in this case "db.collection.find( {'first_name' : 'value_A','last_name' : 'value_B'})" it means "AND" between the fields.

Comment: He mentioned that his query can become :
`db.collection.find({ 'first_name' : 'value_A' })` **or**
`db.collection.find( {'last_name' : 'value_B'})`  **or**
`db.collection.find( {'mail_adress' : 'value_C'})`

Comment: Looks like he is using a form to enter data. I think he's asking how to construct the query ignoring null values. In that case, it has to be done in front end code, not the db query. Let's see what he replies.

Comment: I agree with svjn I really meant "AND" between fields. When I write 'OR' in the question, each query is independent. Exactly ! I am using a form to enter data and I try to construct the query ignoring null values.

Comment: Okay updated the query as an OR of AND's with a check against `null` values

Comment: @Aditya 's answer sounds really nice ! I will try it on my data as soon as I can. However I am wondering if doing this will make the query slower to run ?

Comment: It will not at all be slower to run since for most of the documents `$and` will fail as soon as it enters the particular mongo document so not much time will be needed by it.Additionally, any day one mongo call is better than making two or three calls to your DB.

Comment: You can however, save an inner `$and` if you do not allow `null` value for search by filtering them in the front-end itself.

Comment: I am not sure how to do it in Python, but for sure there should be some way to construct the query in frontend itself. Check for null and ignore the fields with null in queries. Simple.

Comment: @aditya I tried your query it works thanks :). I am going to publish the Python code with your query. I am also going to try to construct the query in front end as svjn suggests.