# (mongoDB) find with empty or null values

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

how to make a mongodb collection find (db.collection.find) with empty values?

currently i have:

```
function test(s) {
    if (!s) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return s;
    }
}

var content = {
    date: { 
        from: '2017-10-15', 
        to: '2017-11-15' 
    },

    'name': 'some text', //this can be null or empty
    'text': 'some other text' //this can be null or empty
}

col.find({
    "date": {
        $gte: new Date(content.date.from),
        $lte: new Date(content.date.to)
    },

    "name": {
        $ne: {
            $type: null
        },

        $eq: test(content.name)
    },

    "text": {
        $ne: {
            $type: null
        },

        $eq: test(content.text)
    },
}).toArray((err, items) => {
    console.log(items)
});
```

but it returns an empty array, because "name" or "text" is null / an empty string, 
i want that it query only the values that have something specified or ignore it (like content.name is something in it or its empty)

how do i get it? i already searched ... but didnt found something

thanks!

( already testet [mongoDB : multi value field search ignoring null fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22857456/mongodb-multi-value-field-search-ignoring-null-fields))

Versions:
Node: 8.9.0
(npm) mongodb: 2.2.33
mongodb: 3.4

Answer (score 0):

Try using $and, $or operators. Something like.

```
col.find({
$and:[
    {"date": {$gte: new Date(content.date.from),$lte: new Date(content.date.to)}},
    {"$or":[{"name": {$ne: {$type: null}}},{"name":test(content.name)}]},
    {"$or":[{"text": {$ne: {$type: null}}},{"text":test(content.text)}]}
 ]
}).toArray((err, items) => {
  console.log(items)
});
```

Comment: tryed to make, when "name" is something (other than empty), it still finds all others, like i have "t1", "t2" and search after "t1" still finds "t2" (name)

Answer (score 0):

```
col.find({
    $and: [
        {
            $and: [
                { 
                    "date": {
                        $gte: new Date(content.date.from)
                    }
                },
                { 
                    "date": {
                        $lte: new Date(content.date.to)
                    }
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            $or: [
                { 'name': null },
                { 'name': content.name }
            ]
        },
        {
            $or: [
                { 'text': null },
                { 'text': content.text }
            ]
        }
    ]
})
```

Edited:

```
col.find({
    $and: [
        {
            $and: [
                { 
                    "date": {
                        $gte: new Date(content.date.from)
                    }
                },
                { 
                    "date": {
                        $lte: new Date(content.date.to)
                    }
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            $or: [
                { 'name': null },
                { 'name':'' }
                { 'name': content.name }
            ]
        },
        {
            $or: [
                { 'text': null },
                { 'text': '' },
                { 'text': content.text }
            ]
        }
    ]
})
```

`null` and `empty` is different, you need to add one more condition for empty string in query.

[Logical Query Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query-logical/)

Comment: with this here, it always responses with empty (array, when .toArray), i already readed this, i found nothing useful in the operators list ....

Comment: This query looks pretty correct to me so you might want to start by not using any filters, see if there's anything coming back and then add the filters step by step to see which one is causing the empty array.

Comment: Also for me this works only if "content.name" & "content.text" has a value... (when only one or nothing from them is defined or empty it always responses with an empty Array)

Comment: i need it so that the input values are null / empty / with string (input) and the query searches it, when it has input and when empty / null then it should ignore it (from the input (content))